# Datatables.js styling is not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to Javascript, but recently needed to use Datatables.js to enhance my html tables but had encountered quite a beginner problem of having no styling or functionalities applied. Would really appreciate your help if you can offer some advice.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table_id"  class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S/N</th>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Contact Number</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Delivery Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>303-123</td>
            <td>Terry Park</td>
            <td>12351329</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $(#table_id).DataTable();
    } ); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your element ID in quotes.

For example:

```
 $('#table_id').DataTable();
```